# Why is this symlink created when repository is initialized?

Tags: .net-core, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I'm developing a tool that utilizes libgit2sharp. Currently using LINQPad 6 running on .net core 3.1 to develop this.

While I was testing, I noticed that an oddly named directory symlink (`_git2_a09040` in this case) is created in the bare repository that I initialized. Last I remembered working with libgit2sharp, no such link is created.

[image]

It is pointing to a "testing" directory which doesn't exist and not typically a file that would expect to see in a git directory. Libgit2sharp just forwards the call to libgit2's `git_repository_init_ext()` function so I think this is coming from libgit2. Some old testing artifact that got into the build perhaps?

**What is this symlink and why is it being added here?**

It doesn't matter so much to me that this is created, I don't think it would negatively impact my project, just curious as to why.

- Win10 Pro x64 1909
- DotNet Core x64 3.1.100
- LINQPad 6 x64 6.6.1 (beta)
- LibGit2Sharp 0.26.2 (nuget)
- LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries 2.0.306 (nuget dep)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a Git repository is initialised, a check is performed to see if the filesystem on which the repostiory is created supports symlinks. This is done by creating a symlink and seeing if that works. If it does not work, `core.symlinks` is set to `false`.

When built for Windows, this check is only performed if `core.symlinks` is `true` which suggests you might have that setting enabled.

The function which tests for this does try to remove the symlink, but does not return an error in case that fails in order not to stop the repository creation from succeeding if this aspect of the check fails.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. I always had it enabled so I guess it was cleaned out before. Is this a libgit2 specific test, or does git do something similar?